# Briefly explain your roles and responsibilities

Tags: interviewing

During an interview and in a consulate interview I was asked to: Briefly explain your roles and responsibilities.

1. What does it mean?
2. Is it what I do on daily basis?
3. How much explaining is enough?

It's really important please answer.

Comment: Who is asking? What is this for? The answer to your questions will vary based on the situation.

Comment: It was asked in interview and in consulate interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're being asked for this in an interview, then just explain what you do on a daily basis.  If there's significant event that you do periodically, put those in too.

And the "how much explaining" aspect is in the first word there - **briefly**

This means a few sentences.  If the interviewer wants more information, they'll ask for more details.

Comment: Your answer holds true for both places "H1B Consulate interview" and "Job Interview" ??

Comment: I answered on the basis of this being a job interview (this being a Workplace specific site).  A consulate interview question is best asked on the [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) site.